# Make clickable image in the middle of screen over the content of site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to put image with jQuery so its clickable and its over the pages content all the time - exactly i nthe middle of screen. Its a banner.
I tried this code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it                     dims out the page content.</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec     aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus     aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
```

what it does is make the image but the position is center of screen - if the page has scrolling, the stuff stays static at 1 point - not center of any screen.

Any help? :(

Answer (score 0):

[**Your website**](http://liveweave.com/Bqqzb4) without CSS seems to work fine. I think your CSS file includes `position: fixed;` Try removing this element. Then it won't be hung on your screen. Hope it helps.